# How to iterate through data and write to excel file quicker with C# and openXML

Tags: c#, excel

I have a pretty simple method that grabs data from an sql query and then puts it inside of a list and finally iterates through two for each loops onto an excel file. It works fine with small amounts of data, but not at all with larger amounts. What would be the best way to iterate and also write to my workbook the quickest? I am using OpenXML.

Here is the code

```
  private UInt32 AddSheets(SpreadsheetDocument document, WorkbookPart workbookPart, Sheets sheets, string sheetName, UInt32 sheetNumber, List<RentalFeeReportingRecord> currentRecordList)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> listofCoreBankingIds = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        listofCoreBankingIds = currentRecordList.Select(x => new { id = x.CoreBankingId, regionName = x.RegionName }).Distinct().ToDictionary(y => y.id, y => y.regionName);
        foreach (var coreBankingId in listofCoreBankingIds.OrderBy(x => x.Value))
        {

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart1 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            string currentCurrency = null;
            string regionName = null;

            Worksheet worksheet1 = new Worksheet();
            SheetData sheetData1 = new SheetData();

            Row rowInSheet1 = new Row();
            Row firstRow = new Row();
            Row lastRow = new Row();

            rowInSheet1.Append(
              excelController.ConstructCell("Region", CellValues.String, 3), excelController.ConstructCell("Merchant - Terminal", CellValues.String, 3),
              excelController.ConstructCell("Fee Charged", CellValues.String, 3),
              excelController.ConstructCell("Currency", CellValues.String, 3),
              excelController.ConstructCell("Processing Date", CellValues.String, 3),
              excelController.ConstructCell("Description", CellValues.String, 3)
            );

            sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);


            foreach (var currentRecord in currentRecordList.OrderBy(x => x.RegionName).ThenBy(z => z.Currency).ThenBy(y => y.DateProcessed))
            {
                if (coreBankingId.Key == currentRecord.CoreBankingId)
                {

                    regionName = currentRecord.RegionName;
                    currentCurrency = currentRecord.Currency;
                    double currentTotal = currentRecord.TotalFeeAmount;
                    string merchant = currentRecord.MerchantRecord.MerchantID + " - " + currentRecord.MerchantTerminalRecord.terminalID;

                    if (currentRecord.IsPinPad)
                    {
                        merchant = merchant + " - PIN Pad";
                    }

                    string description = currentRecord.TerminalRecord.description;
                    if (currentRecord.IsProRated)
                    {
                        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentRecord.DeployedDate.Year, currentRecord.DeployedDate.Month);

                        description = currentRecord.TerminalRecord.description + " (" + currentRecord.MonthlyFee + " Fee \\ " + days.ToString() + " Days) * " + currentRecord.DaysActive.ToString() + " Days Active";
                    }

                    rowInSheet1 = new Row();
                    firstRow = new Row();
                    lastRow = new Row();

                    rowInSheet1.Append(
                      excelController.ConstructCell(regionName, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(merchant, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFee.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 1),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.DateProcessed.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(description, CellValues.String, 2)
                    );

                    sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);

                }

            }


            Columns columns = excelController.AutoSize(sheetData1);

            worksheet1.AppendChild(columns);
            worksheet1.AppendChild(sheetData1);
            worksheetPart1.Worksheet = worksheet1;


            Sheet sheet1 = new Sheet()
            {

                Id = document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1),
                SheetId = sheetNumber,
                Name = regionName
            };

            sheets.Append(sheet1);
            sheetNumber++;
        }
        return sheetNumber;

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Apologies this is openxml

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. Could you be more specific with these: *small amount*, *with larger amount*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be worth doing a high-level analysis of your algorithm's complexity. I won't use big o to keep things simple.

```
// ...
foreach (var coreBankingId in listofCoreBankingIds.OrderBy(x => x.Value))
{
    // ...
    foreach (var currentRecord in currentRecordList.OrderBy(x => x.RegionName).ThenBy(z => z.Currency).ThenBy(y => y.DateProcessed))
    {
        if (coreBankingId.Key == currentRecord.CoreBankingId)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

So:

- for every iteration of `coreBankingId`, you are reordering the `currentRecordList` in **exactly the same way**
- the inner loop only cares about 1 set of values (when the `CoreBankingId` is equal to the outer loop's key)

With those two pieces of knowledge, I suggest you look at using `GroupBy` instead. This code is untested straight into CR and I'm a bit rusty on C# but something like:

```
var groups = currentRecordList
    .GroupBy(r => new { Id = r.CoreBankingId, RegionName = r.RegionName });

foreach (var group in groups.OrderBy(g => g.Key.RegionName)
{
    var coreBankingId = group.Key.Id;

    foreach (var currentRecord in group.OrderBy(x => x.RegionName).ThenBy(z => z.Currency).ThenBy(y => y.DateProcessed))
    {
        // Your loop
    }
}
```

That should have scale much better to bigger datasets.

---

Original suggestion (which I think is wrong):

```
var data = currentRecordList
    .GroupBy(r => new { Id = r.CoreBankingId, RegionName = r.RegionName })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key.RegionName)
    // I can't remember if ToLookup preserves order. If it doesn't, you'll have to tweak this to order later.
    .ToLookup(
        g => g.Key.Id, 
        g => g.OrderBy(x => x.RegionName)
            .ThenBy(z => z.Currency)
            .ThenBy(y => y.DateProcessed)
            .ToList());

foreach (var datum in data)
{
    var coreBankingId = datum.Key;
    foreach (var activity in datum)
    {
        // Your loop body without the if.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Wouldn't I then need a third foreach for activity? That would then still be just as slow as my code correct?

Comment: @Adil15 - nope, I didn't know what to call it but `activity` is the same thing as `currentRecord` in your loop. Sorry, my naming probably didn't help on that. Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: @Adil15 - with a bit more thought, I think I overcomplicated it and did end up having too many levels of enumerable - sorry about that. I've updated the code with something simpler which I think should work.

Comment: your changes are exactly what I ended up doing, with a few differences! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Quick remarks:

- I don't see the point of `listofCoreBankingIds`, especially since you only use the `key`, never the `value`. Just loop through the `currentRecordList`. I'm guessing you might need to `GroupBy` the `CoreBankingId` and loop through that, but your logic is obscured by the creation of that dictionary.
- `currentRecordList` is a bad name IMHO. The "List" part is pointless. Why not call it `rentalFeeReportingRecords` or `currentRecords`?
- Six parameters, almost a hundred lines: I'd turn this method into a class of its own and split it into several descriptively named methods. For instance, the compilation of the `description` could be a method.
- Your logic jumps all over the place. For instance, `worksheetPart1` gets defined early on, but doesn't come into play until almost at the end. Same for `worksheet1`.
- `currentCurrency` is never used. `regionName` only exists because you do the pointless "create dictionary and loop through its items" logic.
- Why the "1" suffix in `sheetData1` and `worksheet1` and `rowInSheet1`?
- Use [string interpolation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) instead of concatenating strings.